# Layout different in all versions of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, alignment

I am having a very confusing problem. On [this site](http://ballardhardware.com/tradeshow), I have the header text lined up properly for all browsers except IE, where the text is raised up to the point where it leaves the header box. Even IE10 has this problem. Here is the code for my header:

```
header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #272727;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px; }

  header .center {
    width: 94%;
    margin-left: 5.5%; }

  header h1 {
    font-family: "Bebas", "Verdana", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1320%;
    float: left;
    width: 21%;
    margin-top: -18px;
    line-height: 102%;
    letter-spacing: -15px;
    color: #e85d00; }

  header .motto {
    font: 400% "Bebas", "Verdana", sans-serif;
    float: left;
    width: 78%;
    line-height: 102%;
    color: white; }
```

As far as I know, there's nothing in here that should give IE trouble, especially not IE10, which is supposed to be comparable to other modern browsers. Is there something I'm missing? Also, I have a font-face declaration for Bebas that works just fine, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please

Comment: Hope a pen is ok: http://codepen.io/SawyerK/full/cBnut

Answer (score 0):

I tested in IE8, IE9 and the text showed just fine. Why do you have `header .center` set to `display:none` in ie.css ? Is this what you mean it "leaves the header" ?

Comment: The reason I have display:none on that is that in the meantime I am replacing the header with an image, I will take that out so you can see what I mean. Also, the web font may not download correctly, which is another reason I switched to an image for IE

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a CSS Reset sheet prior to referencing your bespoke CSS sheet? I tend to find that the IE browser defaults vary from version to version so by using a CSS Reset, it allows your CSS to work from the same foundations across all browsers.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Yes, I have that included. I finally gave up with trying to get it work and instead just replaced all IE headers with an image of the header, which although not ideal is a lot better than writing a conditional style sheet for each version to try and make it work.